# HAProxy is it possible to force basic auth then select AD server based on user IP?

Tags: active-directory, haproxy, http-basic-authentication

Here is my context:

- I have a web application (using HTTPS) which needs users to be authenticated prior to contacting it
- The application expects an HTTP header to be set (let's name it `HEADER`)
- There are ~20 different Active Directory servers instances
- Users need to be authenticated on one of these AD server
- The AD server that needs to be used depends on the IP the user is using

Is it possible to do the following with HAProxy, and if yes, how can I do it ?

1. when a user tries to contact a given URL, if the header named `HEADER` is missing, force basic auth to request the user's `username`and `password`.
2. when receiving `username` and `password` from the user, check the `source ip` and depending on the its value (mask / pattern / whatever) contact the corresponding Active Directory to authenticate the user
3. once the user is correctly authenticated by the selected AD server, write the `HEADER`

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. I posted the same question on Stackoverflow but I guess that serverfault may be a better place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: "Contact the appropriate Active Directory server to authenticate the user"... contact it *how*?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of an old topic, but I figured I'd give it my 2 pence...

You may want to consider using a higher-level tool such as Keycloak + a higher level HTTP gateway (e.g. Apache Knox) to redirect the users, and perhaps use HAProxy to point the users to the closest Knox Gateway available. You could almost have a 1-to-1 relationship between Knox, Keycloak, and AD instances if the distance will really make a difference, and then use HAProxy to choose which gateway to connect depending on the user's IP.

The following project enables users to connect keycloak and knox together:
https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/pontus-keycloak-knox